# Jquery Flot "plothover" event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, flot

I have an issue I can't seem to track down.  I am using Flot to graph some data, super easy.  I want to add the hover effect you see here: [Flot Example](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/interacting.html)

Unfortunately, under no circumstance can I get the 'plothover' event to fire.  This is a brief snippet from the code:

```
$.plot($chartArea, eventData, eventOptions);

$chartArea.bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
    console.log('hovering!');
});
```

Is there something you need to set in the options object to enable this behavior?  Thanks!

Comment: could you show us a workable example of your code on jsfiddle perhaps? It's much easier to spot problems that way.

Comment: You're right, but as soon as I posted this, I realized I forgot something, check out my answer...

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Like an idiot, I forgot to include the grid option.  Check out the object:

```
eventOptions = {
   points: {
        show: true
    },
    lines: {
        show: true
    },
    grid: { hoverable: true, clickable: true },
    xaxis: {
        min:earliestMessage.timestamp,
        max:currentTime,
        mode:"time",
        ticks:10
    }
};
```

notice the grid parameter.  That's what was missing.  Duh!

:)

Comment: Thanks, had the same issue with "plotclick" event, until I realised that I had set grid clickable to false!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what $chartArea is in your code, but lets try something like this:

```
var chartArea = $("#placeholder"); // your chart div

$.plot(chartArea, eventData, eventOptions);

$(chartArea).bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
    console.log('hovering!');
});
```

Comment: is works for me,what is the difference between giving id name and giving the element name.